# Requesting information about Norway

Tags: bicycles, tours, norway

Are there any sites free from snow in Norway in March?
I'm planning an bicycle tour in Norway,so I want to ride bike safely.

Comment: It might be better to do it in the summer.

Comment: It should better,I think.But I must go to there in March.

Comment: Norway is big (long, actually). There's a vast difference in the weather between Oslo and Tromsø in March, and they're over 1000 km apart. Where, specifically, in Norway did you have in mind?

Comment: At first time,I want to go to Lofoten island, but that is very difficult because of snow and bad road conditions.In addition, i have Bergen,sunnmore Alps in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire southern part of the west coast (let's say at least from Stavanger to Kristiansund) is so mild in the winter, that there is usually very little snow there. Ålesund had for example last winter only two days entirely below 0°C. Really cold weather usually only comes together with clear weather, so the combination of freezing temperatures and precipitation as snow is very rare.

The coast of Rogaland (around Stavanger-Haugesund) and Møre og Romsdal (around Ålesund-Kristiansund) is relatively dry with little precipitation at all in the late winter or early spring.

It won't be warm, and you are of course not guaranteed to avoid snow, but chances are indeed high that it will be relatively dry and snow-free in these regions.

Comment: Do check for how busy the roads are. I have only been there one time but it was very busy on a narrow road.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Accuweather for last March, it looks like the weather will be mostly cold-ish, from +6c to -5c pretty much everywhere in Southern Norway ( I looked at Bergen, Kristiansand and Olso).

For example : https://www.accuweather.com/en/no/bergen/258220/march-weather/258220

It can get colder and it can get hotter, it is still winter and there will be snow, there surely will be cold rain on the coast.

Not pleasant.

If you are not used to ride in cold/rain/snow I would not advise doing it.